# Parse.com Invalid Login Parameters

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse's Loginbackground method to authenticate my users. But even though I use the correct credential it throws exception invalid Login parameters, any idea why?

Here is my LoginActivity code:

```
    logInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String muserName = userNameL.getText().toString();
            final String mPassword = passowrdL.getText().toString();

             ParseUser.logInInBackground(muserName,mPassword,new LogInCallback() {
                 @Override
                 public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {

                     if(parseUser != null) {

                         Intent intent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                         startActivity(intent);
                     } else
                     {
                         AlertDialog.Builder Builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (LogInActivity.this);
                         Builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                         Builder.setTitle(R.string.Error);
                         Builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,null);
                         AlertDialog dialog = Builder.create();
                         dialog.show();
                     }


                 }
             });
```

Comment: have you solved this bug? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: I have the same problem, any solutions?

Comment: Signup first from app then try to login it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you posted on the other site

EditText text_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginpage_username);
String login_username = text_name.getText().toString();

EditText text_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginpage_password);
String login_password = ***text_name***.getText().toString(); // ***It should be text_password***